# QT, c++ dlls, and objects

Tags: c++, qt, object, vector, dll

I'm fairly new to dlls, and completely new to QT. I've been playing for a few days and am trying to create a project wherein I read the contents of a file and display the parsed results neatly. I have written a dll to parse the file format and wish to use that dll within my QT GUI.

My dll contains 4 files, SignalParse.h/cpp and Signal.h/cpp.

SignalParse is the meat of the dll, containing the functionality, and Signal is an object for storing data.

My aim is for my QT program to use this function from within SignalParse:

```
__declspec(dllexport) vector<Signal> ReturnSignal()
{
    return sigList;
}
```

sigList is a vector containing all the data from my signal objects. Signal data is something like as follows parsed into variables within the signal object:

```
[SignalOne]
bytes: 2
format: int
offset: 0
```

The aim behind this is to have the GUI able to access the dll and use it to parse files, then read the parsed data.

However, seeing as I am returning a vector of Signal, I (think I) will need to include signal in my QT project. Is this normal practice? Or should I attempt to store my data in another manner?

As a novice, I'm not sure how to handle situations like this. The idea of storing my signal data in an object seems the neatest, but having to then include the object in every program that uses the dll seems less neat.

Perhaps there is a better way of doing it? I would very much like to know whether my approach is reasonable, or if there is another obvious way of handling this kind of thing that I've blindsided.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, including `Signal` will be necessary (and is not a problem).  Why are you creating a DLL rather than a static library?  Static libraries are (in general) much easier to manage.

Comment: Mostly as a learning experience! :) 
Would I need to include both the .h and .cpp or just the .h?

Comment: Usually for dynamically loading a dll, you don't need any .h or .cpp in your program. You dynamically load the dll at runtime and match the dllexport functions in code. This is a good way to 'choose' functionality at runtime as dlls (plugins) will be written to some base interface and you can change runtime behaviour depending on which dll gets loaded.

 If you're trying to dynamically link to the class, you need the .h and library (dll) during compilation for linking.

Comment: You will (obviously) need the .h.  You will also need definitions for all the functions that the clients (potentially) call.  That means not only the named functions, but things like destructors, copy/move constructors.  and perhaps copy/move assignment.  If those functions are inline, fine, if not you will need the CPP file.  Don't forget you will also need definitions of any member functions of any member types that you call.

Comment: @g19fanatic: That is true if you are *dynamically loading* a DLL - but is not true if you are linking to it (like the run-time library for example).